# Access one object from an object collection

Tags: c#, collections, enumeration

Using this function:

```
 public bool CheckCallerStatus(string stConsumerName)
    {
        SelectQuery selectQuery = new SelectQuery("select ExecutablePath from Win32_Process where name='" +
                stConsumerName + "'");
        using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(selectQuery))
        {
            ManagementObjectCollection moc = searcher.Get();
            if (moc.Count > 1)
            {
                return true; // OK process is running
            }
            return false;
        }
     }
```

I can check whether the process, passed in as `stConsumerName`, is an active process (I use `moc.Count > 1` and not `moc.Count > 0` because I'm calling the function from the process I'm observing and trying to see if there are other active processes besides it). Each instance of my process is stored as an object in `ManagementObjectCollection moc`.

Now, I want to get the path of the process. I believe this information is stored in an object in `moc` and a simple `foreach`, like so:

```
string stFilePath = Empty.String;
foreach (ManagementObject process in moc)
{
    stFilePath = process["ExecutablePath"].ToString();
}
```

would return the `path` handsomely.

As you can see I'm storing the value of `process["ExecutablePath"]` to a `string` (and not to a `List` or `array` or somesuch) because I only care about the path of the first process (I'm assuming all the processes returned in `moc` are my process [the name is unique enough]).

**My Question is**: How do I access any *one* object in the `ManagementObjectCollection`? Such that I can set `stFilePath = process["ExecutablePath"];` Since `moc` doesn't support indexing, `moc.First()` or `moc.Single()` won't help.

**And a related Question**: The ManagementObjectClass has a method `GetEnumerable()`. I've looked around (and of course in the MSDN Reference) and I don't really get it. *Does* `GetEnumerable()` *return a indexed collection?*

Comment: Can you use ´break statement´ inside ´foreach´?

Comment: Using a `foreach` to get one item and then using `break` isn't a good idea, since `foreach` is used to iterate over multiple items. This could be slightly confusing when trying to maintain the code later on.

Comment: So does `ManagementObjectCollection` implement the non-generic version  of the `IEnumerable` interface?

Comment: @Grzenio It looks like it. In particular it implements the explicit interface: `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` (Returns an IEnumerator that iterates through the ManagementObjectCollection.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the first object usig LINQ: `moc.First()`, or if you want to validate there is only one object use `moc.Single()`.

EDIT: If `ManagementObjectCollection` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<ManagementObject>` than the above extension methods are indeed not implemented (this is *not* the same as indexer though). You can achieve the same thing manually though:

```
var enumerator = moc.GetEnumerator();
if(!enumerator.MoveNext()) throw new Exception("No elements");
ManagementObject obj = (ManagementObject) enumerator.Current;
string stFilePath = obj["ExecutablePath"];
```

Comment: What about the ["Path"] element? Like this: `moc.First()["Path"]`?

Comment: If the type that `moc.First()` returns (`ManagementObject`) supports indexing (`[]`), that will work.

Comment: @Grzenio it doesn't work. `moc` doesn't support indexing. That's the root of the problem.

Comment: can you use .ToList() in moc?

Comment: @LucasAbilidebob Nope :(

Comment: @Seabiscuit, try the new version please.

Comment: @Grzenio `enumerator.MoveNext()` returns `true` but as per the MSDN `Initially, the enumerator is positioned before the first element in the collection. Reset also brings the enumerator back to this position. At this position, calling Current throws an exception. Therefore, you must call MoveNext to advance the enumerator to the first element of the collection before reading the value of Current.` When calling MoveNext() as we do in the conditional `if (!enumerator.MoveNext())` the enumerable does not advance and it is still positioned at the `Reset` position.

Comment: @Grzenio And that is why your example throws an exception even though the conditional `if (!enumerator.MoveNext())` passes.

Comment: @Grzenio Your solution indeed worked! The reason it originally didn't for me what because in my code I called MoveNext() (as in `moc.GetEnumerator().MoveNext()`) before creating the  `var enumerator = moc.GetEnumerator();` variable. I then lifted your code verbatim and everything fell into place. Thanks!